# блокировка поля ввода EditText программно

Tags: android, kotlin

Как заблокировать поле ввода программно? В Android-Java это было так

```
editText.setFocusable(false)
editText.setLongClickable(false)
```

В Android-Kotlin так не работает

```
editText.focusable = View.NOT_FOCUSABLE
```

а свойства или метода ***setLongClickable*** я не нашел.

Comment: Напишите как в Java, студия вам поможет перевести в property-syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java-вовские сеттеры в Kotlin-е никто не отменял. Пишете как знаете

```
editText.setFocusable(false)
editText.setLongClickable(false)
```

Android Studio вам подскажет, что это немного не по Kotlin-овски. Нажмете два раза Alt-Enter и получите что надо

```
editText.isFocusable = false
editText.isLongClickable = false
```

Готово! Так и научитесь писать сразу через проперти.

Comment: Уважаемый Eugene Krivenja! Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь :)